# MySQL query to retrieve related data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, codeigniter

I'm not too experienced with SQL queries (most times I used query builder from frameworks, like CodeIgniter and Laravel). Now, I need to retrieve data from a relational DB which have two tables: one for entity entries and other for complemental data of entities. For example, see below:

tbl_posts

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem ipsum | lorem-ipsum |
| 2 | Testing post | testing-post |
| 3 | Hello world | hello-world |

tbl_posts_meta

| id | post_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | first_name | John |
| 2 | 1 | last_name | Doe |
| 3 | 1 | rating | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | parent | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | rating | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | rating | 4 |

In this example, I need to retrieve an array of objects in this format:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Lorem ipsum",
    slug: "lorem-ipsum",
    data: {
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      rating: 5,
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Testing post",
    slug: "testing-post",
    data: {
      parent: 1,
      rating: 3,
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Hello World",
    slug: "hello-world",
    data: {
      rating: 4,
    }
  },
]
```

I've tried using subquery to handle this, but I'm reveiving `Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT * FROM tbl_posts_meta WHERE "post_id" = "tbl_posts"."id") as data FROM tbl_posts;
```

I've already tried using JOIN, but the result looks more away from expected (I have one "key" property and one "value" property in result, containing the last found entry in tbl_posts_meta).

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_posts INNER JOIN tbl_posts_meta ON tbl_posts_meta.post_id = tbl_posts.id;
```

Is there someway I can retrieve desired results with one query? I don't want to do this by applogic (like first retrieving data from tbl_posts and appending another query on "data" property, that returns all data from tbl_posts_meta), since this way may cause database overload.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your JOIN query, maybe it has an error, but this should be the solution.

Comment: SQL doesn't have the concept of nested structures like this, so you'll have to retrieve the data and then post-process it. You can still get it all in one go with a straightforward JOIN, you'll just have some repeated data that you don't need.

Comment: @Nino I've added my JOIN query in post. :)

Comment: @IMSoP Searching around internet, I've found some people using subqueries to achieve a result next to what I need. So, I don't understod what you said with "SQL doesn't have the concept of nested structures"...

Comment: I mean literally that: SQL result sets are always defined as a two-dimensional structure of rows and columns. Look at any database client tool, or library for fetching result sets into PHP, etc, and you'll see this assumption baked right in. That's why you get the error you do: you're trying to put multiple columns into one, and there's no way to output that. There may be a few niche products that extend SQL with some way of getting multi-dimensional results, but I've never seen any.

Comment: Isn't there any way for MySQL to return these subqueries as JSON? Maybe, as you said, in table (two dimensional structure) will have a column called "data" (as I defined "{...subquery...} AS 'data'" on my query) containing the result as JSON...

Comment: Without an attempt to debate IMSoP approach, solving your issue is easy with a sub select and group concat, assuming you can format the data later on: [EDIT] not shown correctly here, see answer

Comment: MySQL supports JSON objects. You can simply add another field call data and store the JSON object. ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html )

Answer (score 0):

The code is not shown right in the comment so here it is for you to check, sorry I can't contribute more to the theoretical debate:

```
select 
tp.id,
tp.name,
tp.slug,
(select group_concat(`key`, "=",value separator ';' ) from tbl_posts_meta where post_id= tp.id )as datas
from tbl_posts tp
```

Comment: I've tried this query ```SELECT *, (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(key, value)) FROM tbl_posts_meta WHERE post_id = tbl_posts.id) AS data FROM tbl_posts;``` and the result is exacly what I need! The entries on tbl_posts_meta are returned as JSON in a "virtual column" called data. Now, my challenge is to convert this raw query into an Laravel's Eloquent-equivalent query using Query Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these simple steps to get to your needed json:

- join the two tables to have centralized data
- generate a `tbl_posts_meta` JSON-like string by aggregating on your columns of interest (`tbl_posts.id`, `tbl_posts.name`, `tbl_posts.slug`) using a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function. Since your keys can either be integers or strings, you need to do a quick check using the `CAST(<col> AS UNSIGNED)`, which will return 0 if the string is not a number.
- use the `JSON_OBJECT` function to transform each row into a JSON
- use the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function to merge all jsons into a single json.

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT p.id,
           p.name, 
           p.slug,
           CONCAT('{',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(
                      CONCAT('"', 
                             m.key_, 
                             '": ', 
                             IF(CAST(m.value_ AS UNSIGNED)=0, 
                                CONCAT('"', m.value_, '"'),
                                CAST(m.value_ AS UNSIGNED))  ) 
                      ORDER BY m.id                             ),
                  '}') AS data_
    FROM       tbl_posts      p
    INNER JOIN tbl_posts_meta m
            ON p.id = m.post_id
    GROUP BY p.id,
             p.name, 
             p.slug
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
           JSON_OBJECT("id",   id, 
                       "name", name, 
                       "slug", slug, 
                       "data", CAST(data_ AS JSON))) 
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wAVQeqzLrsJQqgkqXfRMK1/0).

Answer (score 0):

After some research, testing and reading the queries you posted here, I've finally reached the result I needed. The final query is structured this way:

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      key, value
    )
  ) FROM tbl_posts_meta WHERE post_id = post.id
) AS data
FROM tbl_posts;
```

Translating it to Laravel's Eloquent query builder, and using PHP's serialize/unserialize functions, the end result looks like this:

```php
$posts = Post::query()
          ->select("*")
          ->selectRaw('(SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(key, value)) FROM tbl_posts_meta WHERE post_id = posts.id) as data');

return $posts->get()->map(function($post){
  $meta = [];
  foreach($post->data as $dataItem){
    foreach($dataItem as $key => $value){
      $meta[$key] = unserialize($value);
    }
  }
  $post->data = $meta;
  return $post;
});
```

Thank you for your support and attention! :)